# Unable to set format with GwtBootstrap3 datetimepicker

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, gwt

I'm trying to use bootstrap DateTimePicker with java and GWT but I think it sends a null value (for the field date) if I try to set the format of the date with this instruction:

```
datePicker.setFormat("dd MM yyyy hh ii");
```

So far the only solution I've found is to remove that line. But in this way I don't know in what format the DateTimePicker is sending the date, probably the english way and I need italian. I've managed to set the date language that the picker shows, with this:

```
datePicker.setLanguage(DateTimePickerLanguage.IT);
```

but when I pick a date it shows the date in the US format in the field.
I'm searching the web from days without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found where the problem was.
It seems this is the correct code:

```
datePicker.setGWTFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

`datePicker.reload();`

after setting the new format.  The JavaDoc says to call `reload` whenever you change any setting.

Comment: I already found a solution and wasn't that, but can you tell me where you find this information? Thanks.

Comment: Check the java doc of the `DateTimePicker` https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-extras/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gwtbootstrap3/extras/datetimepicker/client/ui/base/DateTimePickerBase.java#L297 maybe you can also provide the solution you found.